# How to order column groups by a cell's value

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

I have a spreadsheet of multiple datasets in columns. I checked some documentation here, https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150, but the SORT() function would order my columns on a column-by-column basis when I want to keep pairs of columns together. The first row has axis labels and the second has dates I want to sort by.

For example, this is what I have.

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| date2 | null | date3 | null | date1 | null |
| 1.000 | .2353 | 1.000 | .3235 | 1.000 | .2823 |
| 2.000 | .4593 | 2.000 | .3852 | 2.000 | .3924 |
| 3.000 | .6372 | 3.000 | .7238 | 3.000 | .6932 |

But I want

| E | F | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| date1 | null | date2 | null | date3 | null |
| 1.000 | .2823 | 1.000 | .2353 | 1.000 | .3235 |
| 2.000 | .3924 | 2.000 | .4593 | 2.000 | .3852 |
| 3.000 | .6932 | 3.000 | .6372 | 3.000 | .7238 |

where date<sub>i</sub> are now sorted.

Answer (score 0):

[image: SORT]

if you think a result like this would suit you, this is the formula:

```
=transpose(sort(transpose({A1:F1;A2,A2,C2,C2,E2,E2; A3:F5}),2,1))
```

Comment: I worded my original question poorly. I have updated the question and example to reflect more closely on what I meant.

Comment: I changed my answer